# MIPS: Using I/O to store and read integers in .Data

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm just learning MIPS and I'm trying to take a user input, store it in .data, and then output it. Here's my current code.

```
.data
test:
.word 4 #make a 4 byte (32 bit) space in memory for a word with address insert_into
Input:
.asciiz "\Please Enter a Positive Integer: " #in unused memory store an integer
Triangular_Output:
.asciiz " is a Triangular Number."
Not_Triangular_Output:
.asciiz " is not a Triangular Number: " 
.text
main:

la $a0, Input #load address Ask_Input from memory and store it into arguement register 0
li $v0, 4 #loads the value 4 into register $v0 which is the op code for print string
syscall #reads register $v0 for op code, sees 4 and prints the string located in $a0

la $a0, test #sets $a0 to point to the space allocated for writing a word
li $v0, 5 #load op code for getting an integer from the user into register $v0
syscall #reads register $v0 for op code, sees 8 and asks user to input a string, places string in reference to $a0

la $a0, test #load address insert_into from memory and store it into arguement register 0
li $v0, 1 #loads the value 1 into register $v0 which is the op code for print integer
syscall #reads register $v0 for op code, sees 4 and prints the string located in $a0

la $a0, Triangular_Output #load address Tell_Output from memory and store it into arguement register 0
li $v0, 4 #loads the value 4 into register $v0 which is the op code for print string
syscall #reads register $v0 for op code, sees 4 and prints the string located in $a0

li $v0, 10 #loads op code into $v0 to exit program
syscall #reads $v0 and exits program
```

I'm getting this

*Please Enter a Positive Integer: 6*

*268500992 is a Triangular Number.*

I know that the issue is that I'm reading the address of test rather than the content but I'm having trouble figuring out how to make it read test.

I'm compiling this in MARS

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed your bugs below. But, before we get to that a few stylistic points ...

---

I always applaud good commenting. Yours are an explicit wording of each instruction. This is because you're just starting and are trying to understand each instruction and what it does.

But, good comments should show intent (i.e.) what the algorithm is doing and not just mimicking the instruction. The instruction is the "how" and the comment should be the "what/why".

So, before I could diagnose and fix your program the first thing I did was thin down the comments a bit. Also, I like to follow the 80 column rule, particularly for asm.

`syscall` really doesn't need a comment [ever] if the `li $v0,...` line has one.

If you're having trouble remembering what a given instruction does, consider a comment block at the top that explains the mechanics of each one once. You're repeating the instruction set reference, but it's better than doing it on each line

---

Here is your code simplified, with the bugs annotated, and fixed:

```
    .data

    # make a 4 byte (32 bit) space in memory for a word with address insert_into
    # in unused memory store an integer
test:       .word       4

Input:      .asciiz     "\Please Enter a Positive Integer: "

Triangular_Output:  .asciiz " is a Triangular Number."
Not_Triangular_Output:  .asciiz " is not a Triangular Number: "

    .text

main:
    la      $a0,Input               # address of string to print
    li      $v0,4                   # syscall for print string
    syscall

    # NOTE/BUG: syscall 5 does _not_ need $a0 to be preset and it returns the
    # read value in $v0
    la      $a0,test                # get address of test
    li      $v0,5                   # syscall getting an integer from the user
    syscall

    # here are two ways to save off the value:
    move    $t0,$v0                 # save to a register that won't be clobbered
    sw      $v0,test                # save to memory location

    # NOTE/BUG: we do _not_ want the _address_ of test, but rather its
    # _contents_ (i.e.) use "lw" instead of "la"
    la      $a0,test                # get address of test
    lw      $a0,test                # get value of test
    li      $v0,1                   # syscall for print integer
    syscall

    la      $a0,Triangular_Output
    li      $v0,4                   # syscall for print string
    syscall

    li      $v0,10                  # syscall for program exit
    syscall
```

---

Here is a slightly slimmer way to write the program:

```
   .data

    # make a 4 byte (32 bit) space in memory for a word with address insert_into
    # in unused memory store an integer
test:       .word       4

Input:      .asciiz     "\Please Enter a Positive Integer: "

Triangular_Output:  .asciiz " is a Triangular Number."
Not_Triangular_Output:  .asciiz " is not a Triangular Number: "

    .text

main:
    la      $a0,Input               # address of string to print
    li      $v0,4                   # syscall for print string
    syscall

    li      $v0,5                   # syscall getting an integer from the user
    syscall

    # NOTE: this assumes we will use the value later -- otherwise, we could
    # replace the _two_ move instructions with a single "move $a0,$v0"
    move    $t0,$v0                 # save to a register that won't be clobbered

    move    $a0,$t0                 # get value to print
    li      $v0,1                   # syscall for print integer
    syscall

    la      $a0,Triangular_Output
    li      $v0,4                   # syscall for print string
    syscall

    li      $v0,10                  # syscall for program exit
    syscall
```

Comment: You could still use `move $a0,$v0` as well as `move $t0,$v0`.  Reading the register whose result was produced earlier is good practice in general, for CPUs that can take advantage of the parallelism.  (Probably an in-order 1 insn-per-clock pipelined MIPS wouldn't care, if it has 1 cycle latency `move` instructions.  But the very simplest pipeline, without forwarding, would avoid a hazard that way.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes. I used `move $t0,$v0` and then `move $a0,$t0` on the assumption that there would be some intervening code that would do something [destructive]. (e.g.) I would have inverted the order of the syscall for the message and the value print to get something like: "Your number is: 73"

Comment: Oh right, I see.  I was skimming pretty quickly and thought you were preserving it across the syscall, rather than *until* the syscall.